# How to make a range from textarea in django

Tags: python, django

I create a simple website that allow user to place their favorite word and search for a capital and one by one processing it at the backend.

for example:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/search">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Now I want to submit a text for example

```
Python
Django
Flask
```

I want to manually split that text and one by one process it
(FOR EXAMPLE CODE)

```
{% for x in textarea_tag %}
   {{ validate_function() }}
{% endfor %}
```

after that, all the result will show under of the form one by one using ajax

(like this)

```
 _____________
|             |
|_____________|

 -Submit-

Word: Python   Cap. Letter: P
Word: Django   Cap. Letter: D
Word: Flask    Cap. Letter: F
```

Sorry for any wrong format, if there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to validate it on server side, you could do something like this in your view post method:

```
def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
    textarea_data_words = request.POST.get('textarea_data', '').split('\n')
    for word in textarea_data_words:
        self.validate_word(word)  # Custom validate method
```

Remember to set a `name='something'` in your textarea to be sure it is send through POST request.

Comment: Yeah I already used that, But i want to make it in the template file

Comment: Do you understand that the template just creates the html is sent to users right? It cannot execute functions on client side. If you want to do it while the html is being generated, you will have to pass the textarea input through context and execute a validation function using a custom django template tag.